# How can choose the three most popular elements ​in an String array and put them in a new String array?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the code:

```
String[] array1 ={"ab", "cf", "cg", "ab", "nf", "ab", "nf", "cf", "cf", "ab"};
String[] array2 = new String[3];

for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    System.out.println(array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
    String[] array1 ={"ab", "cf", "cg", "ab", "nf", "ab", "nf", "cf", "cf", "ab"};
    String[] array2 = Stream.of(array1)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.getValue()))
        .limit(3)
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
```

result:

```
[ab, cf, nf]
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the stream to a map where you can see how oft the appears...

```
final Map<String, Long> occurrences = listOfStrings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(occurrences);
```